# Modify a DIV based on length of a text in another DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I have a series of div's that are populated with an image, title & excerpt.
Many of the 'content' div's have a div with a two lined title, but I'd like for the 'excerpt' div to have a different class added if the title is one lined (24 characters or less).

I figured I'd have a jQuery function that runs through each '.content' div then an if statement compares the amount of characters in the '.contentTitle', if true then it would apply a class to the '.excerpt' div within the same parent .content div.

What I have below is not working. I'm wondering if its because both of the divs (.contentTitle / .contentExcerpt .excerpt) I'm using are children of the container div (.content)

```js
$(".content").each(function(){
  if($(".contentTitle").text().length < 22) {
    $(".contentExcerpt .excerpt").addClass('TEST');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="contentImage"></div>
  <div class="contentTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
  <div class="contentExcerpt">
    <div class="excerpt">
      <?php echo(get_the_excerpt()); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the title something that is input from the user or part of the document being loaded?

Comment: The title is something that is populated dynamically from a database. It's not an input field.

Comment: why don't you just do it on the server?

Comment: @HeyCameron Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the children of the container div (`.content`), you didn't check the children of the div whereas you check all other div matching `$(".contentTitle").text().length < 22` when there is more than one `.content` parent div and when one of them is having the `length >= 22`, the condition will fail.

I have modified the code below to check the children of the parent div.

```js
$(".content").each(function(){
  var parent = $(this);
  if(parent.find(".contentTitle").text().length < 22) {
    parent.find(".contentExcerpt .excerpt").addClass('TEST');
  }
});
```

```css
.TEST {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="contentImage"></div>
  <div class="contentTitle">12345678901234567890123</div>
  <div class="contentExcerpt">
    <div class="excerpt">
      Test content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="contentImage"></div>
  <div class="contentTitle">12345678901234567890</div>
  <div class="contentExcerpt">
    <div class="excerpt">
      Test content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If you replace your code above, you can see, this is not changing the color as one of matching div is having the `length >= 22`.

Comment: @HeyCameron Great :-)